# pgsql2osm? How to generate osm files from osm2pgsql database?

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, osmosis

I  want a method to export osm files from a Postgres database. I already have an osm2pgsql database, an apidb database, and a nominatim database in which I have imported osm files. Now I need to export osm files from a  database with an osm2pgsql schema and use it with the nominatim and api-db(openstreetmap-website) database.

I know that the osm2pgsql is a tool for populating a PostGIS database that allows us to run the Mapnik rendering software, Nominatim search software, or our geospatial queries and have a different database table structure to that required by the openstreetmap-website rails app.

But, I need to create for use in future imports using osmosis and osm2pgsql tools and for backup purposes.

Can anyone help me with how to do this?

Comment: It looks like you have at least three questions embedded in this one. As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question so I think you should research/ask about how "to import a current osm file to PostgreSQL" first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to export an `osm` file from a database with **osm2pgsql** schema.

So I solved my problem creating a database with the [snapshot](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Databases_and_data_access_APIs#pgsnapshot) schema that is a modified and simplified version of the main OSM DB schema.

I've imported my osm file and I recreated the changes that I had made in the database with the osm2pgsql schema in the database with the snapshot schema.

Now, I can import a osm file with **osmosis** of the database with snapshot using the command:

```
osmosis --read-pgsql host="" database="" user="" password="" outPipe.0=pg --dd inPipe.0=pg outPipe.0=dd --write-xml inPipe.0=dd file=file.osm
```

So, I used this osm file to generate my databases for my databases with nominatim, osm2pgsql, and APIDB schemas.